# store result of raw DB in a variable in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I want to run this custom query in Laravel app and save the result in a variable

```
 SELECT MIN(t1.ID + 1) AS nextID
 ROM DB.tablename t1
  LEFT JOIN DB.tablename t2
  ON t1.ID + 1 = t2.ID
   WHERE t2.ID IS NULL
```

I have tried a lot but can't get to save the result in a variable. If I run the above in a mysql console I get an integer value as a result.

I tried the following in laravel but the result is a DBBuilder

```
$result = DB::table('tablename')
                ->select(DB::raw("SELECT MIN(t1.ID + 1) AS nextID
                        FROM DB.tablename t1
                        LEFTDB.tablename  t2
                         ON t1.ID + 1 = t2.ID
                         WHERE t2.ID IS NULL
                    ")
                );
```

Comment: what adding a first() at the end gives you?

Comment: You should add ->get() at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removing the `DB:: table` line and modifying the rest as follows solved the issue

```
DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT MIN(t1.ID + 1) AS nextID
                        FROM DB.tablename t1
                        LEFT JOIN DB.tablename t2
                         ON t1.ID + 1 = t2.ID
                         WHERE t2.ID IS NULL
                    ")
                )['0']->nextID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to find out the next value of auto-increment column if so

```
         SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "yourDataBaseName" AND TABLE_NAME = "yourTableName"
```